# Object not assignable in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/KYveqNv1DnBMTgU60fyg?p=preview) I have a directive that wraps a `div`. The `div` is shown when an `ng-if` condition is true (set with the click of a button).

The directive has a scope element `css` that is an object, where the object has an attribute `width`. Problem is that Angular complains when the directive is shown; see in the console the following error message when the button is clicked:

> Expression '{ width: width}' in attribute 'css' used with directive
>   'modal' is non-assignable!

Note that this problem goes away when the `$timeout` in the directive is removed, but I cannot discard it.

Why does this happen and how to fix it (keeping the `$timeout`)?

HTML

```
<button ng-click="open()">Open modal</button>
<div modal ng-if="showModal" css="{ width: width}">
    <p>some text in modal</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

  $scope.width = '200px';
  $scope.open = function(){
    $scope.showModal = true;
  };
})

.directive("modal", function($timeout) {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'EA';

    directive.scope = { css: '=' };

    directive.templateUrl = "modal.html";

    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {

            $timeout(function(){
                 scope.css.height = '100%';
            },100);

     };

     return directive;

});
```

Template

```
<style>
#modaldiv{
  border:2px solid red;
}
</style>
<div id="modaldiv" ng-style="{'width': css.width,'height': css.height}">
    Some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears since you are not passing a scope variable to your `css` attribute.

You can fix this by creating a variable that holds your css in `ctrl` and pass this variable to the `css` attribute.

Controller

```
$scope.css = {width: $scope.width};
```

HTML

```
<div modal ng-if="showModal" css="css">
    <p>some text in modal</p>
</div>
```

---

**Or alternatively** create a local deep copy of `css` in the directive and manipulate the copy in your `$timeout`.

Directive

```
directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.cssCopy = angular.copy(scope.css);
    $timeout(function(){
        scope.cssCopy.width = '100%';
    }, 100);
};
```

Template

```
<div id="modaldiv" ng-style="{'width': cssCopy.width,'height': cssCopy.height}">
    Some content
</div>
```